Prove an inequality for strongly convex function
Let $g:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R$ be $\mu$-strongly convex. Let $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ have full row rank (so $m\le n$). We are interested in the function $f(x)=g(Ax)$, $x\in\mathbb R^n$.
Let $\tilde\mu=\mu\lambda_{\text{min}}(AA^T)$. Show the following inequality:
$$\nabla f(x)^T(x-x_{\text{proj}})\ge\tilde\mu||x-x_{\text{proj}}||^2,$$
where $x_{\text{proj}}$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ to the minimizers of $f$.

My attempt:
Since $x_{\text{proj}}$ is a minimizer, we have $\nabla f(x_{\text{proj}})=0$. So
$$\begin{align*}\nabla f(x)^T(x-x_{\text{proj}})&=(\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(x_{\text{proj}}))^T(x-x_{\text{proj}})\\
&=(A^T\nabla g(Ax)-A^T\nabla g(Ax_{\text{proj}}))^T(x-x_{\text{proj}})\\
&=(\nabla g(Ax)-\nabla g(Ax_{\text{proj}}))^T(Ax-Ax_{\text{proj}})\\
&\ge\mu||Ax-Ax_{\text{proj}}||^2\quad\text{by strong convexity}\\
&=\mu(x-x_{\text{proj}})^T(A^TA)(x-x_{\text{proj}}).
\end{align*}$$
This is close to the desired result. However, I do not see how to modify this to relate to $AA^T$ instead of $A^TA$. Of course they have same non-zero eigenvalues, but the zero eigenvalues of $A^TA$ seems annoying.
Besides, we did not use the fact that $x_{\text{proj}}$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ (we only used that it is a minimizer). Maybe this is crucial in the proof but I don't see where to use it.

Since $A^{\mathsf{T}} A$ has the same non-zero eigenvalues as $A A^{\mathsf{T}}$, one way forward would be to prove that
$$
x - x_{\mathrm{proj}} \in \mathrm{ker}(A^{\mathsf{T}} A)^{\perp},
$$
the orthogonal complement of the kernel.
Hint: To do so, note that
$$
x_{\mathrm{proj}} = \arg\min_{y} \left\{
\|y - x\|^2 \mid Ay = z_{\star}
\right\},
$$
where $z_{\star} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the (unique) minimum of $g$; you can write down an explicit expression for $x_{\mathrm{proj}}$ here.
